# Nested JSON arrays and FOR loops

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, nested

For the two first objects, province and county i get the right response, but for the nested i get undefined.
can anyone help?

```js
var data =  [
  {
    "province": "massachusetts",
    "county": "barnstable",
    "timeline": {
      "cases": {
        "3/13/20": 0,
        "3/14/20": 1,
        "3/15/20": 1
      },
      "deaths": {
        "3/13/20": 0,
        "3/14/20": 0,
        "3/15/20": 0
       
      }
    }
  }
]
var counties ="";
                for (i in data) {
                    counties += "<h2>" + data[i].province + "</h2>";
                    counties += "<h3>" + data[i].county + "</h3>";
                    for (j in data[i].timeline) {
                        counties += "<h4>" + data[i].timeline[j] + "</h4>";
                        for (z in data[i].timeline[j]) {
                            counties += "<p>" + data[i].timeline[j].case + "</p>";
                            counties += "<p>" + data[i].timeline[j].deaths + "</p>";
                        }
                    }
                }
console.log(counties);
```

Comment: fixed, so that code runs.

Comment: `data[i].timeline[j]` is not a string, it's an object, you can't print it like that inside H4 tags. For index J, why do you use a loop ? there are properties `cases` and `deaths` available. (by the way, you have a `case`, without trailing S, in your code in z loop).

Comment: In your example all `$.timeline`, `$.timeline.cases` and `$.timeline.deaths` are dictionaries and not arrays.
The following expression will return you the case dictionnary: `data[i].timeline.case`. I believe you want to iterate over `case` key-value pairs, and can do so using the `Object.entries()` method [ref here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given my comment on your question, you could do something as follows. This has some limitations (iterates on `cases` only, key of `cases` must exist in `deaths`)

```js
var data =  [
  {
    "province": "massachusetts",
    "county": "barnstable",
    "timeline": {
      "cases": {
        "3/13/20": 0,
        "3/14/20": 1,
        "3/15/20": 1
      },
      "deaths": {
        "3/13/20": 0,
        "3/14/20": 0,
        "3/15/20": 0
       
      }
    }
  }
]
var counties ="";
                for (i in data) {
                    counties += `<h2>${data[i].province}</h2>`;
                    counties += `<h3>${data[i].county}</h3>`;
                    for (let [date, caseCount] of Object.entries(data[i].timeline.cases)) {
                        counties += `<p>${caseCount}</p>`;
                        counties += `<p>${data[i].timeline.deaths[date]}</p>`;
                    }
                }
console.log(counties);
```

Comment: thank you
I was able to modify it to this:
var counties ="";
        for (i in data) {

            counties += `<h2>${data[i].province}</h2>`;

            counties += `<h3>${data[i].county}</h3>`;

            for (let [date, caseCount] of Object.entries(data[i].timeline.cases)) {

                counties += `<h4>Date: ${date}</h4>`

                counties += `<p>Cases: ${caseCount}</p>`;

                counties += `<p>Deaths: ${data[i].timeline.deaths[date]}</p>`;
            }

        }

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed your code and commented on each step:

```
    var data =  [
      {
        "province": "massachusetts",
        "county": "barnstable",
        "timeline": {
          "cases": {
            "3/13/20": 0,
            "3/14/20": 1,
            "3/15/20": 1
          },
          "deaths": {
            "3/13/20": 0,
            "3/14/20": 0,
            "3/15/20": 0
          }
        }
      }
    ]
    var counties ="";

    // Iterate through data entries
    for (i in data) {
        counties += "<h2>" + data[i].province + "</h2>";
        counties += "<h3>" + data[i].county + "</h3>";

        // Iterate through timeline properties ("cases" and "deaths")
        for (j in data[i].timeline) {
            counties += "<h4>" + JSON.stringify(data[i].timeline[j]) + "</h4>";

            // Iterate through cases and deaths properties
            for (z in data[i].timeline[j]) {
                counties += "<p>" + data[i].timeline[j][z] + "</p>";
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(counties);
```